# Wordpress submit button using djeventplanner html plugin

Tags: html, wordpress, form-submit

I have the following code on my wordpress website used for a button in another section (I erased the "link="):

```
[button text="READ MORE" style="default" size="large" target="_self" display="inline" icon="no" class="color2"]
```

I have an html form that needs to be submitted when this button is clicked with the following code that I got from a widget from another site:

```
<input class=portfolio_filter_buttons type=submit value=Submit><input type=hidden name=showlogo value=><input type=hidden name=action value=process><input type=hidden name=djidnumber value=9515><input type=hidden name=source value=>
```

I am not sure how to combine these two so the look of the button is the same as the top code but it still works with the bottom. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you can use Jquery and do like so :

```
$("button.color2").click( function(e) {
 $(":input.portfolio_filter_buttons").click();
});
```

I hope this sweets your needs